# CiviCRM in a Multi-Tenant Setup

Tags: wordpress, drupal, joomla, multisite

Can CiviCRM support a multi-tenant setup, If so what is the best configuration for it? Which CMS tends to work better for these kinds of setups: Drupal, Joomla or WordPress?

Comment: Welcome to SE!  Many configurations are possible... One way of approaching this is to consider what you want the multiple parties to share.  What would be the advantage of your intended plan over multiple separate simple sites?

Comment: No need to share any details. This would be more of a service-based approach to ease our burden of supporting multiple companies.  Not sure that it was do-able so wanted to ask that if you had 1520 clients that they all could be based on a cloud platform like AWS were we could easily update one instance instead of 15 to 20...

Answer (score 2):

It's certainly possible to use CiviCRM as you describe, and I administer a couple of instances that do exactly this.  I know it's possible with WordPress and with Drupal; not sure about Joomla or Backdrop.

However, in each case where I administer such a setup, either a) there's a need to share data, or b) the architecture decision wasn't my own.  In the case where I designed a CiviCRM multi-client architecture (about 25 instances) I opted to have 25 separate instances sharing a git repository (these days I would consider a Docker image instead).  If data sharing isn't necessary, and it's just a way to keep the code in sync, I don't think a multi-site approach is warranted.